# Un-shuffle a compound shuffled list

Tags: java, shuffle

I am trying to un-shuffle a compound shuffled list. I am having trouble figuring out how to accomplish this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Setup random
    Random rand = new Random();
    rand.setSeed(5);
    // Setup list
    ArrayList<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>(Arrays.asList('v','y','2','w','9','n','8','v','a'));
    // Compound shuffle list
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        Collections.shuffle(list, rand);
    // un-shuffle list
    // TODO
}
```

And also my un-shuffle method.

```
private static void unshuffle(ArrayList<?> list, Random rand) {
    // Create the sequence backwards
    int[] seq = new int[list.size()];
    for(int i=seq.length; i>1; i--)
        seq[i-1] = rand.nextInt(i);
    // Traverse the sequence and swapping it inversely
    for (int i=0; i<seq.length; i++)
        Collections.swap(list, i, seq[i]);
}
```

Edit: fixed ArrayList.

Comment: When you say "unshuffle", do you just mean "sort"? As in you are trying to get `list` back to its natural order?

Comment: Yes, i am trying to get the list to its original order.

Comment: Sounds like homework

Comment: Its actually part of an encryption i'm making.

Comment: Writing your own encryption is generally regarded as a Bad Idea(tm). http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own

Comment: I know, i'm using this as a learning experience.

Comment: I don't get this. If you use `rand.nextInt()` you will get totally different numbers to the ones used by `Collections.shuffle` to shuffle the list in the first place. What am I missing?

Comment: @pbabcdefp OP believes it is reversible. Clearly `random` isn't (see also the attempt with `setSeed(5)`).

Comment: Which code segment are you talking about?

Comment: In `unshuffle` you call `rand.nextInt(i)`. How could that possibly undo what `Collections.shuffle()` did? If you wanted to undo `Collections.shuffle()` you would need `rand.previousInt()` or something, but as far as I know you can't find the history of an instance of `Random`.

Comment: If you have time try implementing the unshuffle method, you will find that it works.

Comment: Ok, gknicker's answer shows I'm wrong. Apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"));
        compoundShuffle(list, 8, 13);
        compoundUnshuffle(list, 8, 13);
        System.out.println(list);
    }

    public static void compoundShuffle(List<?> list, int repetition, long seed) {
        Random rand = new Random(seed);
        for (int i = 0; i < repetition; i++)
            Collections.shuffle(list, rand);
    }

    public static void compoundUnshuffle(List<?> list, int repetition, long seed) {
        helper(list, repetition, seed);
    }

    private static <E> void helper(List<E> list, int repetition, long seed) {
        List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int size = list.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            indices.add(i);
        compoundShuffle(indices, repetition, seed);
        List<E> copy = new ArrayList<E>(list);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            list.set(indices.get(i), copy.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not think of creating a parallel integer array to compare the original list to. This is genius.

Comment: @TylerBucher It's the only sane way of doing it. Trying to do `n` `Collections.shuffle` backwards without this trick would be extremely complicated. By the way, thanks for the question. I had no idea `Collections.shuffle` was predictable. I assumed it would use the internal clock (or something), so I've learned something.

Comment: @pbabcdefp Remove the second argument to `shuffle` or use a `SecureRandom` and it isn't.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks for this. I've actually never used the version with 2 arguments before. It's a relief to find out the version I've been using is ok.

Answer (score 2):

Two things you need to know:

1. [Behavior of the Random class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html). This statement is particularly relevant:

> If two instances of Random are created with the same seed, and the
>   same sequence of method calls is made for each, they will generate and
>   return identical sequences of numbers.

2. [Behavior of the Collections#shuffle() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-java.util.Random-). This paragraph is the key:

> This implementation traverses the list backwards, from the last
>   element up to the second, repeatedly swapping a randomly selected
>   element into the "current position". Elements are randomly selected
>   from the portion of the list that runs from the first element to the
>   current position, inclusive.

With that knowledge and a diagram or two, you should be able to figure out how to reverse the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the initial seed of your Random function before shuffling, de-shuffling is indeed possible if you invoke it with the same seed.

In fact the `seed` could be seen as the cryptographic key for this custom (*so not a good choice*) encryption algorithm.

Assuming you are using the Fisher-Yates shuffling algorithm (which I think Collections.shuffle apparently uses) try the following algorithms for shuffling and de-shuffling. It is intended for int[], change it to your Object[].

```
// implementing Fisher–Yates shuffling using a seed
public static void shuffleArray(int[] ar, int seed) {
    Random r = new Random(seed);
    for (int i = ar.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        int index = r.nextInt(i + 1);
        // simple swap
        int a = ar[index];
        ar[index] = ar[i];
        ar[i] = a;
    }
}   

// implementing Fisher–Yates deShuffler
//(you should know the **seed** used for shuffling - this is the decryption key)
public static void deShuffleArray(int[] ar, int seed) {
    //rebuild your random number sequence
    Random r = new Random(seed);
    int[] randoms = new int[ar.length-1];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = ar.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        randoms[j++] = r.nextInt(i + 1);
    }

    //deShuffling
    for (int i = 1; i < ar.length; i++) {
        //use the random values backwards
        int index = randoms[ar.length - i - 1];
        // simple swap
        int a = ar[index];
        ar[index] = ar[i];
        ar[i] = a;
    }
}
```